# Angular2 - Filter array of objects based on value of an object property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-filtering

I have an array of vehicles objects. I have tabs for different vehicle types for eg. 2-wheeler, 4-wheeler etc. While adding vehicle to the collection I am adding its type so my object kind of looks like this.

```
vehicles:[{
  key1:{ name: "Altima",type:"4-wheeler" },
  key2:{ name: "Harley",type:"2-wheeler" },
  key3:{ name: "Jeep",type:"4-wheeler" },
}]
```

Now I am retrieving all vehicles from server and want to add filter on frontend based on type. How can I add the filter for different tabs?

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: you can use `filter` method of the array

Comment: how to get all data form server could you add code here please

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Sorry its a part of project. This is just an example. But something like this. I am using firebase as my database..

Comment: @Aravind by filter do you mean pipe? If yes, I am bit new to this so not sure how to implement one.

Comment: @Dino so I have two tabs on my page. Lets say one for 4-wheeler and another for 2-wheeler. I can filter my data in my .ts file but I was wondering if there is any efficient method for filtering. Angular1 had filter functionality so something like that.

Comment: Why don't you just filter it like an JS array of objects (which it is)? What's wrong with that?

Comment: ok sounds good. will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a pipe using array.filter and use it as follows,

```
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], term: any[]): any {
      if (!term) 
        return items;
      return items.filter(item => item.prefix.indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below code

```
 vehicles:any = [{
                  key1:{ name: "Altima",type:"4-wheeler" },
                  key2:{ name: "Harley",type:"2-wheeler" },
                  key3:{ name: "Jeep",type:"4-wheeler" },
                }];


datavehicle = [];


ngOnInit() {
   let vihicledata= this.vehicles[0];
   var array = Object.keys(vihicledata).map(function(k) {
     return vihicledata[k]
   });

    for(let i =0 ;i < array.length;i++){
      if(array[i].type == "4-wheeler"){
        this.datavehicle.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log('vehicle=>',this.datavehicle)
}
```

Comment: This will definitely work but was looking more efficient solution (may be involving filter).